# Which is the best way to use not null condition,Whether direct condition or using utility methods?

Tags: java, performance, if-statement, conditional-statements, notnull

I want to check the not null condition in many places ,So which way give the best performance..?

1.Whether `if(object !=null){ ... }`

2.Whether `if(Util.isNotNull(object)){...}`

Comment: If `Util.isNotNull` does the obvious thing, these would have approximately the same performance characteristics, though the first will almost certainly be more readable, etc.

Comment: If you can avoid a method call, avoid it.

Comment: First one can be used irrespective of java version. For second java 1.7+ is required. So it is better to use first approach if you are not sure about the java version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first way is a better way to proceed with

```
if(object !=null){ ... }
```

as it will use the [short circuit evaluation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation#Avoiding_the_execution_of_second_expression.27s_side_effects)

Comment: The 2nd way creates odd stack for method isNotNull, like methods is good for addutional cheks, example `isNotEmpty(String txt){return txt != null && txt.lenght > 0}`

Answer (score 0):

Simply do

```
if(obj == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

else{
// Do your computations
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different utility classes available which can be used for checking null and empty values depending on the object which you want to check.
For Strings,you have `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isBlank`, which does the following:
Checks if a String is whitespace, empty ("") or null.

```
 StringUtils.isBlank(null)      = true
 StringUtils.isBlank("")        = true
 StringUtils.isBlank(" ")       = true
 StringUtils.isBlank("bob")     = false
 StringUtils.isBlank("  bob  ") = false
```

For Collection,you have `org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils.isEmpty` which checks if your collection is not null and not empty